# What do we call the angular arcs between two edges of triangles?

Tags: trigonometry, computational-geometry

I've been trying to find a geometry library for java which is as high level as describing angles between adjacent sides of triangles given 3 sides. So, what do we call such kind of arcs. In many geometry books we see arcs describing the angle between edges of triangle and squares for right angles. What are the formal terms for them. Because, I failed to search google successfully due to the insufficiency of vocabulary lately.
I need the terminology to search for java library.
I don't know if my question fits here but any body used such libraries in java here, perhaps some of you might have involved in math projects.
Picture depicts what I wanted...
[image]

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Sometimes they are called the interior angles of the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to a software, `Geometer's Sketchpad`, it may be called [**angle marker**](http://referencecenter.dynamicgeometry.com/gsp-reference-center/index.html?angle_markers.htm).

However, I'm not sure if there's any formal terminology for this.